# Add Texture to entire Subsurface-Model [not only to 1 triangle]

Tags: modeling, texturing

I recently started to use blender. My question is: How do I drape my model, which is a mesh of triangles, with an image texture?

If I select the entire object in the viewport it doesnt give me the option to link a texture to the entire model. I only can manage to add a texture to a single triangle.

Here you can see that once I selecte the entire layertree it keeps the one triangle "selected" so that I only can attach the texture to the one single triangle

[image]

I hope you get what I'm trying to explain. As I mentioned im fairly new to blender

greetings
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get this menu and select *Link Materials*.

[image]

Then all objects will have the same image. If you want to have only one image showing then go to *UV Editing* tab

[image]

First, select all the objects by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>U</kbd> to get this menu. Simply click on *Project from View (Bounds)*.

[image]

I just disabled the Overlays for capturing this image, you will get the final result like this.

Comment: I followed your steps but I didnt really worked out for my case. https://ibb.co/RyM9CK6

Comment: Did you select everything by pressing "A" before doing "Project from View (Bounds)"?

Comment: yes I did, the Image got the same size. https://ibb.co/NZ85fc1 it works to apply the image to every triangle as u explained but I want  1 image for the entire model.

Comment: https://ibb.co/bvNkpxM seems like it linked something. once I press "A" it also select the image on the left side in the UV edititng tab but it dosnt apply anything to the surface

Comment: May I have your file so I could test it myself?